# Printing an odd hash inverted triangle in C

Tags: c

I am trying to print out an inverted hash triangle.

```
./upside_down_oddnumber

###########

  #######  

    ###
```

My work so far -

```
int main(void) {
int row, column;
int size;

printf("Enter size: ");
scanf("%d", &size);

row = 1;
while (row <= size) {

    column = 1;
    while (column <= size) {
        if (row == (4 * size) -1 || row == column) {
            printf("#");
        } else {
            printf(" ");
        } 

        column++;

    }    

    printf("\n");
    row++;
}    
return 0;
}
```

Currently it is printing a diagonal line sideways and I should use the equation 4n-1. How should I proceed from here? Any help will be greatly appreciated!! 
Thanks :)

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk an inverted hash triangle but each row has odd values descending.

Answer (score 1):

Start by examining the arithmetics behind the problem:

- `4*size-1` is the length of the top row of `#`, i.e. the `width` of your printout
- Each row has an offset of spaces
- The number of spaces starts at zero for the initial row, and increases by 2

These three observations should be enough to construct a program. Start row and column numbers at zero for consistency. Each row should be `width` characters long. Decide which character to print using this formula:

```
if (column >= offset && column < width-offset) {
    printf("#");
} else {
    printf(" ");
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/bmMK6W)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your if statement.
The first section `row == (4 * size) -1` is never going to be true, because the row will never be bigger then size, so 4*size will always be bigger then row and thus the statement will never give true.
The second section `row == column` will of course give you the line.
You should rethink your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do

```
for(i=size; i>0; --i)
{
    for(j=0; j<(4*size-1 - (4*i-1))/2; ++j)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(j=0; j<4*i-1; ++j)
    {
        printf("%c", '#');
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

`(4*size-1 - (4*i-1))/2` will give the number of spaces that must be printed at the start of each line.

After printing the required number of spaces, the `#`s are printed out.

You could also use

```
printf("%*s", (4*size-1 - (4*i-1))/2, "");
```

instead of the loop to print the spaces.

The `*` in `%*s` is used to specify the width of the string to be printed.